# send multiple data from mysql to a php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

how can I send multiple data from mysql to a php array and echo the first two entries?
In my database I have the columns name, xkoord, ykoord.
I have tried with json, but I guess this doesn't work. What I have is the following:

```
function load_db($var, $xkoord, $ykoord){
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT $var FROM armydb WHERE xkoord = '$xkoord' AND ykoord = '$ykoord'") OR DIE ('Fehler!'); 
$json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json );
}
```

I call this function this way:

```
<?php 
$name_array = json_decode(load_db('name', 1, 0), true);
echo $name_array[0];
echo $name_array[1];
?>
```

This doesnt work.
 Any Suggestion?

Comment: If those variables come from user input you should be using prepared statements or you will leave yourself open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `return`, not `echo`:

```
return json_encode($json);
```

`echo` just prints its argument, it doesn't return it to the caller of the function.

Also, `$name_array` will be a 2-dimensional array: the first dimension is the rows of the results, the second dimension is an associative array of the columns. So `$array[0]` is an array, you can't usefully echo that. You should do:

```
echo $name_array[0]['name'];
echo $name_array[1]['name'];
```

Why are you using `json_encode()` in the first place? Why not just return the array?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function load_db($var, $xkoord, $ykoord){
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT $var FROM armydb WHERE xkoord = '$xkoord' AND ykoord = '$ykoord'") OR DIE ('Fehler!'); 
$resultset = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $resultset;
}

print_r(load_db('name', 1, 0));
```

you don't have to encode the result to json since you can just `return` the data and pass it between functions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it easier

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from armydb where xkoords = '$xcords' and ycords = '$cords'");
// now if you need 1 row;
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['name']; 

// if u need more then one 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 echo $row['name'];
}

?>
```

Comment: If I do so, and the first name in my db is Dasy, i only get a D echoed, not the complete text, why is that and what can I do to get the complete name?

Comment: @SaschaKrause You would get that if you did `echo $row['name'][0]`. Indexing a string returns the character at that position.

Comment: `name` should be quoted: `echo $row['name']`.

Comment: Added quote to name tx @barmar.

Sascha be sure you are using exacly code. i thing you use $row['name'][0]; you just have to use $row['name']. If you want to use more then 1 row i suggest use while.